# Show that if If $|\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k| < \infty$ then $|\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty}E_k| > \limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty}|E_K|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

edit: typed inequality going the wrong way!! Oops haha

If $|\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k| < \infty$ then $|\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty}E_k| > \limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty}|E_K|$

Where $\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty}E_k=\bigcap_{k=1}\bigcup_{j=k}E_j$ and $|*|$ denotes the measure of a set, and all sets are assumed to be measurable.

This is a big confusing for me... It's hard for me to compare the sides of these inqualities since the left hand is the measure of a set after performing the complicated set operation of $\limsup$, while the other side is a sequence of positive real numbers. Help greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is not true. For example, $E_k=[0,1]$ for $k$ even, $E_k=[1,2]$ for $k$ odd. Then $\limsup_k E_k=[0,2]$.

Comment: It is true, though, if you assume that $E_1\subseteq E_2\subseteq E_3\subseteq\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

I think your inequality goes the wrong way.

Note that for any $n$, $ \left|\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_k\right|\geq \sup_{k\geq n}|E_k| $ thus $$\left|\limsup_n E_n \right| = \lim_n \left|\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_k\right| \geq \lim_n (\sup_{k\geq n}|E_k|)  = \limsup_n (|E_n|)$$

---

The strict inequality is false. With Lebesgue measure and $\forall i, E_i=[0,1]$ we have $|\limsup_n E_n| = |[0,1]|=1$ and $\limsup_n (|E_n|)=1$, while $|\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k| =|[0,1]|= 1 < \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$.

Applying the lemma of Fatou wrt counting measure we find:$$\left|E\right|-\left|\limsup E_{n}\right|=\int_{E}1-\limsup\mathbf{1}_{E_{n}}=\int_{E}\liminf\left(1-\mathbf{1}_{E_{n}}\right)\leq$$$$\liminf\int_{E}1-\mathbf{1}_{E_{n}}=\liminf\left(\left|E\right|-\left|E_{n}\right|\right)=\left|E\right|-\limsup\left|E_{n}\right|$$or equivalently:$$\limsup\left|E_{n}\right|\leq\left|\limsup E_{n}\right|$$

The equality is not strict as will become clear if we let $E_n$ not depend on $n$.